# CSP Content Security Policy - Why are we not using it?

Tags: security, xss, content-security-policy

I'm now introducing CSP and other security-related http headers to the website that I work on. They all feel like a walk-in-the-part to introduce so no problem there...

I quickly investigated what sites where using what http headers. Surprisingly extremely few sites where using CSP. I checked out some banks login-pages, some big websites and some technology-driven websites (like stackoverflow). Facebook was the only site I could find that used CSP. Gmail only runs it in report-only mode.

For me it feels like a low-hanging fruit to just add these headers and get all the security benefits. I feel confused. Have I missed something? Why are not anyone using it? Is there some kind of drawback that I don't know about?

People from Google and Mozilla where editors of the W3C spec. So why aren't even they using it?

Comment: *"People from Google and Mozilla were editors of the W3C spec. So why aren't even they using it?* - A few points here. First, I believe Robert Hansen of WhiteHat Security was the creator of CSP. Second, I believe Brandon Sterne was the first to implement it in FireFox. Third, CSP is being tuned or tweaked. [CSP Level 2 is a draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/) in LC.

Comment: 1. Yes but Brandon Sterne, Mozilla and Adam Barth, Google where editors. So they invested time in it. 2. Im talking about sites using it, not browsers that supports it. 3. Yes but I still think level 1 is great so my question is valid even though a bettet level is on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to provide a link-only answer, but I don't know a better way to answer than [Why is CSP failing? Trends and Challenges in CSP Adoption](http://mweissbacher.com/publications/csp_raid.pdf). Maybe citing Section 3.4, Conclusions, will add some substance:

> While some sites use CSP as an additional layer of protection against
>   content injection, CSP is not yet widely adopted. Furthermore, the
>   rules observed in the wild do not leverage the full benefits of CSP.
>   The majority of CSP-enabled websites were installations of phpMyAdmin,
>   which ships with a weak default policy. Other recent security headers
>   have gained far more traction than CSP, presumably due to their
>   relative ease of deployment. That only one site in the Alexa Top 10K
>   switched from report-only mode to enforcement during our measurement
>   suggests that CSP rules cannot be easily derived from collected
>   reports. It could potentially help adoption if policies could be
>   generated in an automated, or semi-automated, fashion.

---

Unofficially, (or maybe officially, since Neil Matatal is with the CSP working group), from [Managing Content Security Policy](http://speakerdeck.com/oreoshake/bsidesla-managing-content-security-policy):

- CSP Level 1

  - 2 years of study
  - could not remove inline scripts
  - FAIL

- CSP Level 2

  - two weeks
  - managed risk with script nonces
  - SUCCESS